# Passing arguments to css class in Angular

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

How can I pass a parameter to a css class in angular ?

```
.div-disabled[status="true"]
{
 pointer-events: none;
 opacity: 0.5;
 background: #CCC;
}
```

In my .ts file , I have disableDiv = true;

Tried the following, doesnot seem to work.

```
<div status="{{disableDiv}}" class="div-disabled"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

**css file**

```css
.div-disabled[status=true] {
    pointer-events: none;
    opacity: 0.5;
    background: #CCC;
}
```

**html file**

```html
<div [attr.status]="disableDiv" class="div-disabled"></div>
```